# I went to upgrade to The Trusty Tahr (supported) and now my vagrant box is broken

Tags: vagrant, localhost, ubuntu-14.04, ubuntu-12.04

Now my local dev box is broken. Throwing this error when i try to vagrant reload:

```
The following SSH command responded with a non-zero exit status.
Vagrant assumes that this means the command failed!

shutdown -h now

Stdout from the command:



Stderr from the command:

sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified
```

Comment: Well, it's a Vagrant box. Blow it away with `vagrant destroy` and recreate with `vagrant up`. That's the entire point of Vagrant.

Comment: lol... i guess you're right in a way.  =] @ceejayoz

Comment: ssh into the VM and run the command `sudo shutdown -h now` yourself to see whats happening